# Android. Enable Microphone when Display is off

Tags: android, adb, microphone

I have a `CAT S62 PRO Smartphone`. My problem is that the microphone gets disabled when the Screen is turned off. I can not give commands to the `Google Assistant` or use a Sleep tracking App because the microphone doesn't work. But when I call someone or use an Phone-like app the Microphone works fine, even the Display is off. I already checked the Permissions a "normal" user can change in the Setting.

I need this for my `Motorcycle Intercom (Sena)` to control my Smartphone while driving.

Is the a Secret setting or an `ADB` command i can use to enable the microphone for normal Apps when the Screen is off?

Android Version 10

Answer (score 0):

Look, it is not possible in some devices. Including Android One devices, if the microphone is not working while the screen is off - It is totally depend on device manufacturer.
One Plus provide this feature.
Now, you are listing about the scenario while you are on phone call and the screen is getting off.
**This is handled by proximity sensor** 
While you stand by the device using power button. The device analyse that you put off screen.
*Understand this as proximity sensor has higher priority than power button screen stand by.*